# jquery load function doesnot work inside keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem. I have this simple html code.

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="">
    <div>
        <p>
            <input id="query" type="text" size ="60" title="Enter your search string here." style="font-size:12px;" />
            <input id="startSearch" type="button" value="Search Resource" />
         </p>
    </div>

    <div id="pageContents" >

    </div>
</form>
```

and I am using this Jquery code to run my program

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#query').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            alert( 'enter key is pressed ');
            $('#startSearch').click();
        }
    });

    $('#startSearch').click(function() {
        query = $('#query').val();
        model = $('input:radio[name="model"]:checked').val();
        if(model=='combined'){
            $('#pageContents').load('combinedsearch.jsp?q='+encodeURIComponent(query)+'&m='+model);
        } else {
            $('#pageContents').load('search.jsp?q='+encodeURIComponent(query)+'&m='+model);
        }

    });
});
```

issue is:  `$('#startSearch').click(function()` works well when someone press start search button. but `$('#query').keypress(function(e))` captures event and process my code but never show results back to the browser. I thinks load function is not working inside `$('#query').keypress(function(e))` function. Can anyone please guide me

Comment: If you put an `alert()` inside the `click` handler, does it show?

Comment: yes, it alert the message. Actually it process combinedsearch.jsp page but never load it back to pagecontents div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$('#query').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert( 'enter key is pressed ');
        $('#startSearch').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing too much ;) It's a form, and its "main event" is a `submit` - which happens when someone hits "enter" or clicks the submit button.
Thus your HTML should look like this:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input id="query">
  <input type="submit" value="Search Resource" />
</form>
```

and your JS:

```
$(function(){

  // DOM ready

  $('#myform').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    // Your search code
    // ...

  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, This is the right way to use it. I vote it up. Just Read [jQuery Submti](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use keypress. Use `keydown` or `keyup`.

As stated in the jquery api:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official
>   specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may
>   differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried both keydown and keyup. Even with these two It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to my fiddle this works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/65HSm/

HTML:

```
<div id="pageContents"></div>
<input type="text" id="query">
<input type="button" id="startSearch" value="search">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#query').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            alert('enter key is pressed ');
            $('#startSearch').click();
        }
    });

    $('#startSearch').click(function () {
        query = $('#query').val();
        model = $('input:radio[name="model"]:checked').val();
        if (model == 'combined') {
            console.log('load 1');
            console.log(query);
            $('#pageContents').load('combinedsearch.jsp?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&m=' + model);
        } else {
            console.log('load 2');
            console.log(query);
            $('#pageContents').load('search.jsp?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&m=' + model);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: yes, it captures the event keydown/keypress/keyup and trigger click function for startSearch element. My code process but results are never loaded into #pageContents div